# Draw something at bottom of the last row in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, custom-controls, customization

I know how to draw and actually I can draw (in this case it actually looks like an Add button). The problem raised is when there are many rows enough to take in the vertical scrollbar, the grid does not have space for my Add button to be drawn.

I've tried solving that issue by setting `AllowUserToAddRows` to `true`. This will bring in a new row that should give me enough space to draw the Add button on.

But another issue occurred is I need to prevent the behavior of the new row (enabled by `AllowUserToAddRows`) completely, such as by default when the last row has something entered and finished entering, the new row is always added and ***adds a new item to the underlying bound data***. Although I draw my add button completely covering the appearance of the new row but actually it's still there and bound to the underlying data.

That's really not acceptable at all. I'll try intercepting some key stroke like TAB, ENTER (on the last row) but looks like that's not enough.

So to solve my problem, we have 2 approaches:

- Set `AllowUserToAddRows` to `false` and somehow make DataGridView give me a space at the bottom of the last row (even when there are many rows and the vertical scrollbars appear). This way I can always draw my button expectedly and avoid the nasty behavior of the `AllowUserToAddRow`.
- Set `AllowUserToAddRows` to `true` and somehow prevent the default behavior of adding new row by some standard user's interactions (ending editing, tabbing, entering, ...) - actually we need that the new row cannot be added by another way other than by clicking on the Add button (that I draw).

Any approach is fine (although I prefer the first, the second may work almost the time but still buggy somehow - I really don't believe in its feasibility and reliability).

Here is my try (following the second approach, because I have no clue to solve this following the first approach).

```
//override some messages
protected override void WndProc(Message m){
     //keydown
     if (m.Msg == 0x100){
        var vk = m.WParam.ToInt64();
        //for the last row
        if (CurrentCell.OwningColumn.DisplayIndex == ColumnCount - 1)
        {
            //intercept the TAB and ENTER
            if (vk == 0x9 || vk == 0xd){
                return;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

### Update

Another bothersome bug of Winforms (maybe they call it a feature). Actually the `DataGridView` still leaves us a space at the end (when there are many rows) BUT once it's added to some special layout panels like `GroupBox`, `TableLayoutPanel`, ... it will not share any space as by default. To avoid placing it in some layout panel is sometimes not easy to accept, we can customize some GroupBox (using normal Panel) but we cannot easily customize a `TableLayoutPanel`. I think this opens to another approach (the third approach).

Comment: You could make room by incresing the row height of the last row, maybe?

Comment: @TaW but it's not easy to draw the last row normally, I did think of  that approach.